# Incremental additions in cmd

Tags: cmd.exe

I hope somebody can help.

I want a batch file to check for a updated version of something
so I have

SET VERSION=001

then further on

SET /a VERSION+=1

but when you ECHO %VERSION% it show as 2, not 002, can it be shown as 002?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow your SET command with two further commands:

```
if %VERSION% lss 100 set VERSION=0%VERSION%
if %VERSION% lss 10 set VERSION=0%VERSION%
```

Then you will have the format you want.